# Removing edges in a graph to create disconnected components

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Say, I have a graph that is bipartite and connected, i.e., it doesn't contain disconnected components to start with. I need to remove a few edges (no specific number) to make the graph disconnected. Google searches for an algorithm for the same only show results for min k-cut algorithms. In my case, "k" is not known in advance and as such "k" is not an input the algorithm. Meaning, I don't really have a specific number of edges that need to be removed. Any number of edges will do, as long as its minimum. What is an efficient algorithm for this problem? Again, google is not helpful as there seem to be tons of such algorithms. Can someone make some recommendations?

Comment: Are you looking for a [global min cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm#The_global_minimum_cut_problem)?

Comment: That looks right. But I cannot use a contraction algorithm since I need to preserve all the nodes.

Comment: Use Gusfield's algorithm then.

Comment: Thanks David. I will check it out!

Comment: Gusfield's algorithm seems like a good fit. Are there any libraries that implement this already?

Comment: Yes, but none that I personally vouch for.

Comment: Sorry, but I have another request. I found this paper but the algorithm description is very terse - https://deinfo.uepg.br/~jcohen/pdf/2011-ica3pp-parallel-gusfield-cut-tree-algorithm.pdf. Do you have any references for a detailed description?

Comment: I don't know about detailed, but the English version is, number the nodes 1..n, and initialize a tree where 1 is the root and the other nodes are its children. For each s from 2..n, let t be its current parent and compute the s--t max flow (e.g., via Edmonds--Karp). For each of s's siblings u in s+1..n, if u is reachable from s in the residual flow network, make s its parent. The global min cut is the cut arising from the max flow invocation with the least flow.

Comment: Thanks! I found this btw - https://jgrapht.org/javadoc-1.4.0/org/jgrapht/alg/flow/GusfieldGomoryHuCutTree.html